# Failing to boot from USB on Windows 10, Dell Inspiron 5323

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, windows-10

I have a USB with Ubuntu 14.04 on it, but I can't find a way to boot from it. When I do Advanced Startup with the Windows 10 interface, there are plenty of "devices" to select from. They appear in the Bootable Devices list as: ubuntu, setup, Removable Device, USB Storage Device, Hard Disk, and other unrelated devices. All of these names appear regardless of whether or not I have my Ubuntu USB plugged in.

Clicking on the "Ubuntu" option title simply brings me to a GRUB interface, and all the other options bring me straight to Windows 10 again. I tried to do it from my BIOS boot menu, but when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> during start up for the Boot Menu, it seems like it starts to go to the Boot Menu but then cancel it and go straight to Windows 10 again. How can I get my USB to boot?

[image: first screen of boot menu]

[image: result of clicking ubuntu in boot menu]

Comment: GRUB interface - have you already tried installing ubuntu? Any screen shot that you can share?

Comment: Yes. I used to have Linux Mint installed, but I want to switch to Ubuntu. I can no longer access my Linux Mint partition either.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in alternate way as well. Check here

http://www.howtogeek.com/126016/three-ways-to-access-the-windows-8-boot-options-menu/

Only thing is you need to set the Boot order correct and another important thing is how you copied your ISO file to USB. It is not a direct copy check http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows for more info

Comment: I used Universal USB Installer to put Ubuntu onto my USB. And I am using Windows 10, not Windows 8. I can already access the boot menu, but none of the options on the boot menu lead to the Ubuntu setup.